# jQuery .fadeIn() setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide

I have a few elements which I want to `$('.hidden_item').fadeIn()` when the button is clicked.

So in order to do that I need to first hide them. I tried using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden_item').hide();
});
```

But sometimes page *onload* sends heartbeat and my elements ***hidden_elements*** stay visible for some time. So I would like to hide them with CSS.

What styling I should use to correctly hide them for later `$('.hidden_item').fadeIn()`?

Comment: Start them hidden using CSS rule i.e. `.hidden_item{display:none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`.hidden_item{
  display:none;
}`